# Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS doesn't recognize my usb keyboard and mouse

Tags: 14.04, usb, keyboard, mouse

I'm new to Linux and I decide to give Ubuntu a shot. My keyboard is working on the screen where I select ''try Ubuntu'' but when Ubuntu finishes loading I can't do anything because my USB keyboard and my USB mouse don't work.

I looked for people with a similar problem to mine but I don't understand the answers. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try unplugging and replugging it again?

Comment: Yes I tried but it's not working. I tried with another usb mouse and nothing either.